# Delete Site on Central Administration

Tags: central-administration

I did an oopsie with central administration on SharePoint 2010. Instead creating site collection, i create a site within the ca. I tried to delete it by go to site setting > sites and workspaces > delete the site as well as go in to the site > site action > site settings > delete this site. I couldn't delete this unwanted site off the central administration. Any thought on deleting this?

Comment: the way i create the site is on central administration > site actions > new site

Answer (score 2):

You can delete using stsadm command:

stsadm -o deletesite -url http://servername/sites/sitename

Comment: is there's another way to delete it with out using command promt?

Answer (score 1):

you can go to subsite ,click on site settings,site action -delete site.

http://centraladmin/subsite/_layouts/deleteweb.aspx

Comment: this is the same with one i did try which is site action > site settings > delete this site

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
stsadm -o deletesite -url http://servername/sites/sitename
```